# How to replace image name that starts with img and ends with jpg

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this kind of url

```
<a href="http://alatpancing.tk/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/img20170926_055740_d_solid_ring_stainless_steel_1-4.jpg"><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-5906" style="outline: 1px solid blue;" src="http://alatpancing.tk/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/img20170926_055740_d_solid_ring_stainless_steel_1-4-300x225.jpg" alt="" width="300" height="225" /></a>
```

I want to replace "img20170926_055740_d_solid_ring_stainless_steel_1-4.jpg" the name of the image with other name.

What i've tried so far.

```
var url_img = '<a href="http://alatpancing.tk/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/img20170926_055740_d_solid_ring_stainless_steel_1-4.jpg"><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-5906" style="outline: 1px solid blue;" src="http://alatpancing.tk/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/img20170926_055740_d_solid_ring_stainless_steel_1-4-300x225.jpg" alt="" width="300" height="225" /></a>';
url_img.replace(/^img/, 'other url');
```

Comment: `\/(img.*?\.jpg)`?

Comment: @ctwheels nope - what you're suggesting will start matching at `/img` of the `a` tag's URL - which is different than the THUMBNAIL url in the `img` tag - Which makes the question incomplete aswell.

Comment: Andrew... What about the large size image URL enclosed in the `a` tag? Don't you think your question misses some more insight in order to get a good precise answer? - Also, why you use HTML instead of using the URL string alone?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan If there's an intention to replace one over the other, it should have been specified by the OP. In any case, the OP should use an HTML parser and get attributes that way, then use my code to replace the part they want.

Comment: @ctwheels your suggestion is a good starting point but somewhat incomplete ;) - But yes I agree about most of your previous comment.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan well that's why I didn't post it as an answer haha, it's more of a nudge in the right direction :)

Comment: ctwheels Thanks a lot and if for example i want to check end of string be jpg or png

Comment: @Andrew png vs jpg ? What? Now everything makes less sense.

Comment: check if it ends with png or jpg

Answer (score 0):

First of, you have two different *`img***.jpg`* URLs

- One for the **large image** `<a>` `href` attribute
- One inside **thumbnail image** `<img>` `src` attribute

`img20170926_01_foo_1-4.jpg             // a href`
`img20170926_01_foo_1-4-300x225.jpg     // img src`

all enclosed within a **HTML string** (not `url_img` like you named your variable).

### Solution

If you really are unable to get those **two** urls separately - here's the best you can do:

- Use a **DOMParser** to convert your string to actual Elements
- Extract the `href` **attribute value** of the `<a>` Element
- Extract the `src` **attribute value** out of the `<img>` Element
- The the **thumbnail suffix** "`330x225`" can be extracted by comparing the two strings

```js
var HTMLString = '<a href="http://alatpancing.tk/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/img20170926_055740_d_solid_ring_stainless_steel_1-4.jpg"><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-5906" style="outline: 1px solid blue;" src="http://alatpancing.tk/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/img20170926_055740_d_solid_ring_stainless_steel_1-4-300x225.jpg" alt="" width="300" height="225" /></a>';

// HTML string parsing
var domParser = new DOMParser();
var doc = domParser.parseFromString(HTMLString, "text/html");

// Let's do some extraction
var img_large = doc.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].getAttribute("href");
var img_thumb = doc.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].getAttribute("src");
var img_extension = img_large.split(".").pop();
var img_thumbnail_suffix = img_thumb.substr(img_large.replace("."+ img_extension, "").length).replace("."+ img_extension, "");
var img_name = img_large.split("/").pop();
var img_name_no_extension = img_name.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, "");
var img_is_expected_format = /^img\d{8}_/.test(img_name);

console.log(
"Image Large URL: "+ img_large,
"\nimage Thumbnail URL: "+ img_thumb,
"\nImage extension is: "+ img_extension,
"\nThumbnail suffix is: "+ img_thumbnail_suffix,
"\nImage name is: "+ img_name,
"\nImage name (witnout extension) is: "+ img_name_no_extension,
"\nIs expected format of 'imgYYYYMMDD_'?: "+ img_is_expected_format
);
```

Having extracted the **Image pure name** and it's **extension** you can  finally `HTMLString.replace()` with surgical precision:

```js
var HTMLString = '<a href="http://alatpancing.tk/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/img20170926_055740_d_solid_ring_stainless_steel_1-4.jpg"><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-5906" style="outline: 1px solid blue;" src="http://alatpancing.tk/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/img20170926_055740_d_solid_ring_stainless_steel_1-4-300x225.jpg" alt="" width="300" height="225" /></a>';

// I Hardcoded the values - OFC, see previous example above how to get those values.
var img_name_no_extension = "img20170926_055740_d_solid_ring_stainless_steel_1-4"; 
var img_extension = "jpg";   

// Let's do some replacements now!
var img_new = "img20180131_000001_foo_bar_1-1"; // The new image name
var reg1 = new RegExp(img_name_no_extension, "g");
var HTMLReplaced = HTMLString.replace(reg1, img_new);

// The same way replace the extension if needed...

console.log(HTMLReplaced);
```